# Improper integral of $\frac{1}{|x|^{pa}}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

Let $a,p$ be real numbers and $a\gt1$.Which of the following statements are true?

$1$.If $p\gt 1,\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|x|^{pa}} dx \lt \infty $

$2$.If $p\gt \frac{1}{a}$ then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|x|^{pa}} dx \lt \infty $

$3$.If $p\lt \frac{1}{a}$ then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|x|^{pa}} dx \lt \infty $

$4$.For any $p\in \Bbb R$ we have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|x|^{pa}} dx = \infty $
For this question if I separate the limit of the integral from $-\infty$ to $0$ and $0$ to $\infty$.
 $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x|^{pa}} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{|x|^{pa}} dx $+ $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|x|^{pa}} dx $
               $-\int_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{x^{pa}} dx$ + $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{pa}} dx $.After solving this I am facing problem in limit substitution.

Comment: 1,2,3 are in contradiction with 4.

Answer (score 1):

For $pa\neq 1$ You have:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x|^{pa}}dx=2\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}(\frac{1}{1-pa}|T|^{1-pa}-\frac{1}{1-pa}|t|^{1-pa})$$
and You have
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}(\frac{1}{1-pa}|T|^{1-pa}-\frac{1}{1-pa}|t|^{1-pa})=\infty$$
for any $T$ if $1-pa<0$ and $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}(\frac{1}{1-pa}|T|^{1-pa}-\frac{1}{1-pa}|t|^{1-pa})=\frac{1}{1-pa}|T|^{1-pa}$$
if $1-pa>0$.

If $pa=1$ You have
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x|^{pa}}dx=2\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}(\ln|T|-\ln|t|).$$
Can You take it from here?

Comment: Yes,I got it.Thank you.

Comment: You´re welcome!

Comment: :can you explain last part of the limit?

Comment: Which last part do You mean exactly? In any case the integral is infinite!

Comment: Ifpa=1,In the limit, ln(0) doesn't exist. How can it be infinity?

Comment: You have $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}(\ln|T|-\ln|t|)=\infty$ for every $T$ since $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\ln|t|=-\infty$. It´s true though that it doesn´t exist.

Comment: You should add something like "Which of the following four statements is true?" to Your post and explain the problems You encountered when trying to find the true statement.